# Create a loop in R and save the result as a dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I want to apply the following loop on **data** (which is a dataframe with 18 obs. of 11 variables). My results are only a dataframe with 18 obs. and 1 variable

```
results <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=18,ncol=11))

for (i in 1:11){
 results <- (data[,i]-(data[,(i-1)]))
 }
```

So to specify my question: I want to subtract every column from "data" with the next smaller column. So column 1 - column 0, column 2 - column 1 and so on, the end would be column 11 - column 10. And I want to save my "results" as a data frame

Comment: Welcome to SO. Great that you provide reproducible input. But (1) what operation do you want to perform, how should the data look like after, (2) What is your question or issue you are having..

Comment: Provide example data, and expected output, you might not need forloop at all: something like `result <- df1[, 1:3] - df1[, 2:4]`

Comment: please specify what your result should look like.

Comment: I want to subtract every column from "data" with the next smaller column. So column 1 - column 0 , coloum 2 - column 1 and so on, the end would be column 11 - column 10. And I want to save my "results" as a data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matrices are indexed from 1,

```
set.seed(123)
data <- matrix(rnorm(18 * 12), nrow = 18)
results <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 18, ncol = 11))

for (i in 2:12){
  results[,i - 1] <- data[,i] - data[,i - 1]
}
```